# How to show multiple attachements together with Scribu's Posts 2 Posts connector?

Tags: loop, attachments, plugin-posts-to-posts

I am using Scribu's [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin to connect *posts* with small galleries attached to an *album* post type. Everything works great, except that I cannot figure out how to merge the attachments to display together.

Right now I am using the code below to display each gallery one below another.

```
$images = get_children( array( 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => 999 ) );

if ( $images ) {
    $total_images = count( $images );
    $image = array_shift( $images );
    $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'thumbnail', $default_attr );
}

if ($images)
    echo do_shortcode('[gallery size="small" columns="5"]');
```

Is it possible to grab all of the post attachments connect to an *album* and combine before this script is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just have to call get_children() for each gallery:

```
$images = array();

foreach ( $gallery_posts as $gallery ) {
  $images = array_merge( $images, get_children(
    'post_parent' => $gallery->ID,
    ...
  ) );
}
```